# Best estimate of among groups variance with unequal within groups variances

Tags: anova, variance, bias, unbiased-estimator, bias-correction

**Goal**

I have about 100,000 sets of groups. For each set, I would like to measure its among groups variance in order to then make comparisons among sets.

**Description for each set**

In each set, I have $N$ groups. For each group $i$, I have an estimate of the mean $\bar x_i$ and of the variance $\sigma^2_i$ by sampling $n$ individual (with replacement) in each group.

Let's define $\bar x$ as the overall mean, $V_G$ as the measured variance among groups and $\bar \sigma^2$ as the mean variance among groups:

$$\bar x = \frac{\sum x_i}{N}$$
$$V_G = \frac{\sum (\bar x_i - \bar x)^2}{N-1}$$
$$\bar \sigma^2 = \frac{\sum \sigma^2_i}{N}$$

The best estimate for the among group variance $\sigma^2_G$ is

$$\sigma^2_G = V_G - \frac{\bar \sigma^2}{n}$$

, where $\frac{\bar \sigma^2}{n}$ is the expected variance among groups if all groups have the same mean (that is the variance of the sampling distribution).

**Problem**

The above formula to calculate $\sigma^2_G$ assumes that the variance within each group are equal that is $\bar \sigma^2 = \sigma^2_i \space \forall \space i$. Under violation of this assumption, the estimate of the among groups variance is biased. *Am I right so far?*

I cannot assume equal variance. In fact the magnitude of this violation (and the number of groups $N$) depends on the specific set of groups.

**Question**

How to calculate the best estimate of the among groups variance?